# BizTalk - Where does the deployment details stored

Tags: biztalk

For a BizTalk project, where does Studio stores the deployment details? I opened the dtproj and csproj files in notepad, but found relative entries which store the deployment details (like application name, Db name etc).

Answer (score 2):

The servername and managementdatabase name are stored in the ".btproj.user" file.

```
<VisualStudioProject>
    <BIZTALK>
        <Build>
            <Settings>
                <Config
                    Name = "Development"
                    RestartHostInstances = "False"
                    Register = "True"
                    Redeploy = "True"
                    ConfigurationDatabase = "BizTalkMgmtDb"
                    Server = "MYSERVER"
                />
```

The applicationname are stored in the ".btproj" file

```
<VisualStudioProject>
    <BIZTALK>
        <Build>
            <Settings>
                <Config
                    ApplicationName = "MyBTSApp"
                />
```

The reason for having database and server config in the '.btproj.user' (which normally is not under source control) is that the Visual Studio deployment feature main focus is for development scenarios where one users settings might differ from another.

Answer (score 1):

It basically exports its "c:\documents and settings[user]\Application Data\Microsoft\Deployment\BindingFiles" or somewhere around there.

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the project and browse it's property sheets.  You'll find the necessary entries.  Now keep in mind, this is only for deployment from the dev studio.  You want to change control your binding files like source code in your deployment packages.